# building Kubeflow in private GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow, gke-networking

When trying to deploy kubeflow on a private GKE using `kfctl`, I get the following error:

```
validatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/cert-manager-webhook configured
ERRO[0656] Permanently failed applying application cert-manager; error:  (kubeflow.error): Code 500 with message: Apply.Run  Error error when creating "/tmp/kout196638265": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": the server is currently unable to handle the request  filename="kustomize/kustomize.go:206"
Error: failed to apply:  (kubeflow.error): Code 500 with message: kfApp Apply failed for kustomize:  (kubeflow.error): Code 500 with message: Apply.Run  Error error when creating "/tmp/kout196638265": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

I checked the github issues and they are not really helpful. Has anyone used `kfctl` yaml file to bring up kubeflow on a private GKE?

Comment: Please provide more details like tutorilas you used, what version of apps are you using. Some configuration files in case if reproducing behaviour will be needed.

Comment: @PjoterS I try to run it with kfctl(1.0.0 and above)
If you follow deploy kubeflow with cli on gcp (you need to run build instead of apply and make some changes to be able to run it)
the cluster comes up and the Kustomize tried to deploy packages on it... but the webhook cert manager cannot get resolved. it keeps trying it till it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone faces the same issue, open port 6443 from master to nodes.
I had to check out our very restricted network and find out.Creating a firewall rule for that port will fix it.